# Alternating program

Tags: muscle, strength, programs, personal-training, programming

What do you think about a program that has 3 different full body workouts each week and changes every month?

Let me explain this further

Month 1:

Full body A = High volume core and arms low volume everything else

Full body B= High volume legs and low volume everything else

Full body C= High volume back and low volume everything else

Month 2 is the same but exercises change, if in month 1 the front squat was my main lift in month 2 the back squat becomes my main lift and so on..

The program goes like this Month 1 > month 2 > month 1> .....

Comment: I don't think that good idea is to do high volume exercises whole week for one group of muscles. Rest is very important part of training.

Answer (score 1):

If you frequently change the way you train, it becomes very hard to follow if you are improving on them. The most important thing in weight training is "progressive overload". This must be followed, there must be an increase in the "total volume load" you are doing. (TVL = weight x rep x set)

Therefore, try to stick to a single program; and try to milk it as long as possible.